# Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class' when i was trying to use firebase with angular i got this error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-cli

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path
>   ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'. Error:
>   Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path
>   ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\mjha3\Documents\Ang_proj\paper-kit-2-angular-master\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)

this is the error I am getting. My project was fine untill I tried firebase database.
I tried my best to solve this but now I need help. Following are something that I have tried so far:

1. I uninstall the **"@angular-devkit/build-angular"** then install it again
2. I change the version of devkit from package.json
3. I updated @angular/cli

still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Nevermind guys! I fixed this issue. I just replace the package.json file with the previous one and now it is working. Thanks

Comment: That does not really help us, who are having the same issue.

Comment: Please try to remove all the files except your code files and then install the angular package again. Still, if you get the error then, please ask in detail.